# Jenkins AWS Steps authentication error accessing s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins, aws-steps

## Background

I am attempting to upload a file to an AWS S3 bucket in Jenkins.  I am using the steps/closures provided by the [AWS Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws) plugin.  I am using an *Access Key ID* and an *Access Key Secret* and storing it as a username and password, respectively, in *Credential Manager*.

## Code

Below is the code I am using in a declarative pipeline script

```
sh('echo "test" > someFile')
            
withAWS(credentials:'AwsS3', region:'us-east-1') {
    s3Upload(file:'someFile', bucket:'ec-sis-integration-test',  acl:'BucketOwnerFullControl')
}
            
sh('rm -f someFile')
```

Here is a screenshot of the credentials as they are stored globally in Credential Manager.

[image]

## Issue

Whenever I run the pipeline I get the following error

> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 5N9VEJBY5MDZ2K0W; S3 Extended Request ID: AJmuP635cME8m035nA6rQVltCCJqHDPXsjVk+sLziTyuAiSN23Q1j5RtoQwfHCDXAOexPVVecA4=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: AJmuP635cME8m035nA6rQVltCCJqHDPXsjVk+sLziTyuAiSN23Q1j5RtoQwfHCDXAOexPVVecA4=

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

## Trouble Shooting

I have verified the Access Key ID and Access Key Secret combination works by testing it out through a small Java application I wrote.  Additionally I set the id/secret via Java system properties ( through the script console ), but still get the same error.

```
System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", "<KEY_ID>")
System.setProperty("aws.secretKey", "<KEY_SECRET>")
```

I also tried to change the credential manager type from username/password to aws credentials as seen below.  It made no difference

[image: different credential type]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be a bucket and object ownership issue. check if the credentials you use allow you to upload to the bucket ec-sis-integration-test.

Comment: I used the key on this exact bucket in a sample Java application which makes me think it's not the key

Comment: Try to upload it via aws cli just to be sure .  In jenkins you don't need to encode  the id and the password to base 64 password. Once i did it and it cause  the 403 too